# Can we run CSV import in Netsuite through WebServices?

Tags: netsuite

- I want to give NS webservice a call
- Upload the CSV file
- Ask NS to run the CSV import through webservices call ?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, I think you could create a process like this:

1. Upload file to NetSuite using Web Services.
2. Save the internal ID of the file in the file cabinet.
3. Call RESTLet and provide file internal ID as a parameter.

The RESTLet would schedule the CSV import (nlapiSubmitCSVImport) using the file internal ID as the primary file. This is an asynchronous call. You'd have to call back to NetSuite to check status and see if the import ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Why not transform the CSV file into XML via {insert favorite language}, and POST to the system via web services?? Seems like less effort.

Comment: You could do this, but if we are talking about CSV imports here then the record limit is significantly higher vs the record limit for web services (25k vs 100, currently). If you are already using CSV imports then it is likely that you are importing / updating more than 100 records.